# Why isn't this mask working in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

I must be missing something...why isn't this working? Instead of clipping to the circle the entire 800x800 backdrop image is displayed...

```
var mask;
var img;

function preload() {
  game.load.image('back', 'backdrop.jpg');
}

function create() {
  img = game.add.image(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY,'back').anchor.setTo(0.5);
  mask = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
  mask.beginFill(0xffffff);
  mask.drawCircle(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 600);
  img.mask = mask;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/karasutengu/2zhv1pwt/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I have no formal experience in `phaser.io`

I was able to fix this in your fiddle by changing

```
img = game.add.image(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY,'back').anchor.setTo(0.5);
```

to

```
img = game.add.image(0, 0, 'back');
```

[JSFiddle Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/m775Lsvp/)

I would assume that placing the image in the `centerX`,`centerY` position results in the mask being offset of the image. Hopefully someone with more experience than I could explain the specifics here, but I will research further and update my answer as I figure out the why to go along with the how.

**Update**

Okay so I've done some digging through the documentation. First, you want to use `img = game.add.image(0, 0, 'back');` due to the fact that the `x` and `y` parameters in this case dictate the upper-left origin of the image, not the center. By using `game.world.centerX` and `game.world.centerY` you are trying to throw the background image to the center of the canvas even though the canvas is the same size as the image.

using `.anchor.setTo(0.5)` from what I can gather, is attempting to set the anchor point at which the image originates to the `centerX` position. However, when you remove this anchor, suddenly the mask works, even though it is not showing correctly (because the position of the background image is incorrect).

**Theory** - By anchoring the image, I believe that it is no longer possible to apply a mask to it. By all experimenting that I've done, having an anchor set on the background image prevents it from being masked, so the mask simply is added as a child to `img` and is placed as it's center, thus why you are seeing the white circle instead of the circle properly masking the image.

Comment: And thank you, I've never even heard of `phaser.io` until I spotted this question while studying javascript for a cert exam coming up. This looks very interesting.

Comment: @Kenji Make sure to accept his answer so he receives credit

Comment: I'm still going through the documentation to figure out why this works the way it does, when I figure this out I'll edit my answer to expand upon it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some additional comments based on my own findings. I should point out that some of it is based on documentation, and some of it is working theory based on experimentation.

Comment: Thanks for investigating this James!

Answer (score 1):

it appears I was a mistaken about the fluidity of the api in trying to chain that last function call... if I break it up:

```
img = game.add.image(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, 'back');
img.anchor.setTo(0.5);
```

it now works!

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/karasutengu/2zhv1pwt/14/)

Comment: Good to know, I didn't consider breaking those up.